# Python: Configparser - escape newlines?

Tags: python, odoo, configparser

Is there a way to escape newlines using ConfigParser?

There is this option `--addons-path` in config where you can provide multiple paths for addons, but paths are long and there are many of paths so writing everything in one line, looks really bad. So I thought to put addons paths in multiple lines, but ConfigParser does not allow it. I get this error:

```
Starting odoo-server: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 68, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/cli/server.py", line 180, in run
    main(args)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/cli/server.py", line 140, in main
    openerp.tools.config.parse_config(args)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/tools/config.py", line 358, in parse_config
    self._parse_config(args)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/tools/config.py", line 403, in _parse_config
    self.load()
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/tools/config.py", line 605, in load
    p.read([self.rcfile])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /etc/odoo-server.conf
    [line  3]: '/home/oerp/openerp80/addons,\n'
    [line  4]: '/home/oerp/openerp80/community-addons\n'
```

Is there a way to write paths in multiple lines, but make ConfigParser treat it as one line (ignoring newlines)?

**Update**

Config file sample (works):

```
someparam = blabla
; this is part I want to modify
addons_path = /some/dir1,/some/dir2,/some/dir3
; some other params
```

Config file I want to look like, but it does not work:

```
someparam = blabla
; this is part I want to modify
addons_path = /some/dir1,
/some/dir2,
/some/dir3
; some other params
```

P.S. Indentation can be different as long as I could put paths in multiple lines, so it would not just go into one long line.

Comment: Can You post that part of the config file? How it looks currently (without errors) and how you want it to look like (with multiple lines)

Comment: @Traveller take a look at updated question.

Comment: Did You look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser

Comment: Sorry I ment this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399665/new-lines-with-pythons-configparser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers before were a step in the right direction.

In Odoo 9 it works like this (You need to indent the lines and keep the commas but it's still possible to have multiple paths in one line.):

```
[options]
addons_path =
    /some/dir1,
    /some/dir2,/some/dir3,
    /some/dir4,
    /some/dir5
```

To achieve this in an older version you can modify the *odoo/openerp/tools/config.py*

Search this line

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(x)))
```

and replace it with this

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(x.strip())))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you indent the lines that add information to your `addons_path` parameter, they will be parsed as one string. Complete example, no commas needed between values (I am using `StringIO` for better demostration, in most cases you will have a file object):

```
import ConfigParser
import StringIO

config_as_string = '''
[something]
someparam = blabla
; this is part I want to modify
addons_path = 
  /some/dir1
  /some/dir2
  /some/dir3
; some other params
'''

config_as_file = StringIO.StringIO(config_as_string)

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(config_as_file)

addons_path = config.get('something', 'addons_path')
```

Then the `addons_path` is a single string:

```
>>> print addons_path

/some/dir1
/some/dir2
/some/dir3
```

And as list:

```
>>> addons_path.split()
['/some/dir1', '/some/dir2', '/some/dir3']
```

Do these examples help? The key is indentation, I guess.

Comment: It does not work. The thing is first it goes through ConfigParser, then it goes through Odoo check where it expects single string and that string is split by comma. If I make any indentation, then that indentation is added into path and then that path is not found (because it splits by comma). If I keep only `\n`, then I get ConfigParser error as in the question.

Comment: Well... you need the same string parsed by two separate pieces of code, where each makes its own arbitrary assumptions... Good luck with that...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to store things in a map if a map is what you're storing
(or a list in your case) and after fetching just use a parser to read the values as they are defined

Like this:

```
[Section]
map1:  {key: value,
          key: value,
          .
          .
          .
}
list1:  [value1,
          value2,
          .
          .
          .
]
```

If You want to just make ConfigParser read multiple lines as if they were in a single line that refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399665/new-lines-with-pythons-configparser):

It basicaly states that:

The ConfigParser _read() method's .doc string says:

```
Continuations are represented by an embedded newline then leading whitespace.
```

Meaning that Your solution would be doing something like this:

```
[SECTION]
param=
  item1
  item2
  item3
```

**NOTE:**
*This has not been tested and Is a re quote from another post.
I'll remove this if someone confirms this works*