# Nicely parsing a multiline config file in python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, configuration-files, configparser

I need a config file to generate my scripts.

```
[PATHS]
elements = elementA,elementB,elementC,elementD,elementE,elementF,elementG,elementH,elementJ,elementK
```

As you notice after a point the line gets too long. I can not keep track of the elements written in it and does not look nice at all.

In my script I do the following to read `elements`:

```
elements = config["PATHS"]["elements"].split(",")
```

Is there a nicer way to handle this? I would prefer something that includes linebreak and tabs, for example:

```
[PATHS]
elements = 
    - elementA
    - elementB
    - elementC
    - elementD
    - elementE
    - elementF
    - elementG
    - elementH
    - elementJ
    - elementK
```

Any suggestions from the more experienced are welcome too.

I tried splitting with `.split("\n\t\t- ")` but did not do the work

---

```
print("1",config["PATHS"]["elements"])

1 
- elementA
- elementB
- elementC


print("2",config["PATHS"]["elements"].strip())
2 - elementA
- elementB
- elementC


print("3",config["PATHS"]["elements"].strip().split('\n'))
3 ['- elementA', '- elementB', '- elementC']
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable: `config`?

Comment: `config type: <class 'configparser.ConfigParser'>`; if you are asking for `elements` it should be a list of strings

Comment: Is the `-` important to you? Can the elements just be each on their own line?

Comment: not important, just would be a nice-to-have for readability. The elements can be each on their own line, with a little bit of indentation

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399665/new-lines-with-pythons-configparser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
elements = [
    element.strip(' -')
    for element in config["PATHS"]["elements"].strip().split('\n')]
```

Comment: seems to do the job! just out of curiosity, which one of the `strip()` and `split()` is applied first? Want to know what happens internally...

Comment: `strip()` removes default whitespaces, `split('\n')` creates a list separating the elements whenever it sees a `\n`, `strip(' -')` removes ` -` from each of those elements

Comment: I've always been partial to `s.splitlines()` vs. `s.split('\n')`.  `splitlines` is OS-line-ending aware, plus I just find the no-arg function call cleaner-looking.